# Exclude Setters and Getters in JaCoCo Code Coverage

Tags: code-coverage, setter, getter, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

With the `cobertura-maven-plugin` setters and getters can be excluded from code coverage using the `ignoreTrivial` option. Is there also such a possibility with the `jacoco-maven-plugin`?

This is my current configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.1.201405082137</version>
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>com/welovecoding/web/blog/test/**/*.class</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>amend-unit-test-java-agent-option</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>report</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>report</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer, possible for `Gradle`?

Comment: Yes, I am still looking for an answer!! :-)

Comment: What about <exclude>some/package/model/**/*</exclude> and <exclude>some/package/dto/**/*</exclude> when u have packages which contains mostly trivial code ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From JaCoCo 0.8.0, it is possible to exclude the getters / setters (and also `toString()`, `equals()`, ...) automatically generated by **Lombok** from the coverage metrics thanks to [filtering options](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/wiki/FilteringOptions#lombok) :

> ### *Lombok*
>
> *Methods annotated with @lombok.Generated (generated by Lombok getters, setters, equals, hashcode, toString, etc) - Done in 0.8.0*

To that end, you will first need to create a [`lombok.config`](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration) file located for example at the root folder of your projet, with the following contents :

```
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

The `@Generated` annotation will be added to the setters / getters, etc. and will be skipped in the coverage analysis.

Answer (score 13):

Not supported officialy, see comments in :

> https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/15

mentioned solution:

> It's a long time since this issue is opened. It a really interesting feature. For instance it's implemented in clover and corbetura. There are fork that implement filtering : 
>   github.com/huangxiwei/jacoco , 
>   https://github.com/mchr3k/jacoco since the begining of the year. Why don't you merge those fork into master branch ? Even if all filtering is not implemented at start, main filters needed are listed in the wiki page you have written (Try with resources, sync block, enum static methods). Coverage is a very useful tool, more it's accruate more it's will be usefull. It helps alot when coverage reach a high value, it helps to focus on the right classes.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link! I wrote to the GitHub issue. Maybe there will be enough votes to get this feature.

Answer (score -6):

I recommend to use Cobertura that does not have such limitation and also does not have so many false positive warnings.

Comment: False positive about what ?

Comment: Cobertura has a barely existent community and has bare bones (at best) support for java 8.