# Sonarqube - Code coverage exclusions for XSD, lombok and slf4j logger generated classes and data objects

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I need to set exclusions for Code coverage exclusions for XSD, lombok and slf4j logger generated classes and data objects

I know SonarQube allows to set coverage exclusions at file level. Is there also a global setting we can use to exclude coverage anlaysis for data objects. As an example.

These classes can be identified by scanning annotation “@XmlAccessorType”, “@XmlRootElement”, “implements Serializable” etc. These classes usually don’t contain any business logic except setters/getters. Also few generated classes have extension of “extends BaseResponseEdge” and “extends BaseResponseMiddle”.

Also Exclude slf4j Logger objects, static constants and final class variables from Integration test coverage.

BTW, I use mvn + jacoco + surefire + failsafe for code coverage implementation

Thanks,
Manny

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592437/exclude-setters-and-getters-in-jacoco-code-coverage/ regarding Lombok generated objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set exclusions at both the project and global levels.

Since you want to exclude by file contents, take a look at the [Ignore Issues section](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues) of the docs. It shows you how to ignore issues raised
* on files that contain a string matching your regex
* between regex-specified start and end markers
* from specific rules on file paths matching a pattern

Code coverage exclusions aren't as fine-grained. You can only exclude by file path pattern.